# XML Parsing and storing the data and retriving the data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

Here in my project i receive a xml file, in which the flow of the project is decided,  my project contains video player to play video files,  a audio recorder to record voice and a application form to get information regarding the user,  but here the flow is completely dynamic each time i receive an xml in which the next screen to display is not fixed.

Here i know to parse the xml but i have to know which collection structure is good to store and retrive (collection structure such as mutablearray, mutabledictionary, plist, or sqlite)
else can i use beans or any other method is there please help me.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say implementing "beans" that are logically sound with your flow logic, then have a mapper maps the XML to the beans (create beans base on the XML). This way you decouple your flow logics from the XML file format, so later on if you decide to use JSON or the XML file format changes, all you have to do is to change the mapper.